# After tweaking Ubuntu 12.04, desktop only shows default GTK-Theme

Tags: 12.04, themes, appearance

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 Amd64 on my laptop but when I use some applications I get ugly looking menus and buttons, Windows 95 like. If I try to change the theme from the appearance settings it doesn't work. Here are some pictures of what I'm talking about

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried a few things I saw online but they haven't done the trick. I'm kind of wondering how I can get a more modern menu and toolbar, the more default ubuntu looking one.

**EDIT**

Ran "gnome-settings-daemon" and got errors. Here is what it said.

```
=== xinerama setup Configuration ===


Clone: false
  Output: Laptop attached to LVDS-0
     status: on
     width: 1366
     height: 768
     rate: 60
     primary: true
     position: 0 0
  Output: (null) attached to VGA-0
     status: off
     width: -1
     height: -1
     rate: -1
     primary: false
     position: -1 -1
  Output: (null) attached to HDMI-0
     status: off
     width: -1
     height: -1
     rate: -1
     primary: false
     position: -1 -1
  Output: (null) attached to DisplayPort-0
     status: off
     width: -1
     height: -1
     rate: -1
     primary: false
     position: -1 -1
=== Applying Configuration Configuration ===
  Clone: false
  Output: Laptop attached to LVDS-0
     status: on
     width: 1366
     height: 768
     rate: 60
     primary: true
     position: 0 0
  Output: (null) attached to VGA-0
     status: off
     width: -1
     height: -1
     rate: -1
     primary: false
     position: -1 -1
  Output: (null) attached to HDMI-0
     status: off
     width: -1
     height: -1
     rate: -1
     primary: false
     position: -1 -1
  Output: (null) attached to DisplayPort-0
     status: off
     width: -1
     height: -1
     rate: -1
     primary: false
     position: -1 -1

(gnome-settings-daemon:3649): Gdk-WARNING **: The program 'gnome-settings-daemon' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)'.
  (Details: serial 263 error_code 8 request_code 140 minor_code 30)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the GDK_SYNCHRONIZE environment
   variable to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
```

Comment: have you tweaked around with the settings? i.e. did you change anything in the default settings or is this how it's been since the time you installed 12.04?

Comment: That's how it was when I first installed it.

Comment: "I tried a few things I saw online but they haven't done the trick." Like what? Maybe they made things worse? Could you create a new user account and see how things look there?

Comment: I created a new user account and it still looked the same. I tried things like editing the gnome-settings dameon.desktop file, stop nautrilius, changing themes etc.

Comment: Do you have a folder called `.themes` in your home folder? Use `ls -a` from the command line or first press `Ctrl+H` if you're using the file manager. If you have such a folder, is it empty?

Comment: Yeah it is. I just checked it.

Answer (score 0):

As my reputation is too low to add a comment I'll add it here instead.
Have you installed the applications through wine, and not the native ubuntu applications? For example with the .exe files instead of through the package manager or with a deb-file?

Comment: Nope not at all. Most of the applications I downloaded were through  Ubuntu Software center

Comment: The other installs I made were .deb files no .exe files

Comment: So have you or have you not installed software from outside the Ubuntu Software Center?

Comment: What have you installed? Too much to give a list?

Comment: I installed everything from from ubuntu software centre except chrome that I installed using sudo dpkg   whcih was a .deb file. There was nothing I installed using wine or that was a .exe file.

Comment: Did you install a separate swt-gtk package when you installed eclipse? It seems like that has caused the same trouble before.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default GTK+ theme, and you're probably seeing it because `gnome-settings-daemon` is not running. You could try just running it from a terminal and see if it gives an error.

Why this would be happening in a fresh install, I don't know, but the errors may give you a clue.

Comment: Isn't what OP's seeing the "fallback" (Raleigh) rather than the default which I think is Ambiance?

Comment: Cool cool I ran gnome-settings-daemon and I got some errors. Check the edit to see them.

Answer (score 0):

Try to switching your theme to default one `Ambiance` from Appearance.

Goto System Settings -> Appearance -> Look (Tab) -> Theme (Section)

and select `Ambiance (default)` from drop down.

Comment: Doesn't work. My current theme in appearance is Ambiance.

Comment: Just a try:
Create a new user and switch to newly created user. And see what theme does apply?

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem. Install gtk-theme-switch:

> sudo apt-get install gtk-theme-switch

Run it:

> gtk-theme-switch

And choose e.g. Ambiance.

I've gone through many topics, finally this is what worked for me, hope it does for you too.